# Recover DB after mirroring

Tags: sql, recovery, mirroring

I have this doubt. If i have a SQL 2012 database with a mirrored database and if i stop the mirror... the mirror database will not be accessible, it will be to "In recovery" status. What would happen if i execute:
"restore database DB with recovery"

Will it become accesible and have the last data that was synchronised?
Or will it restore the data from the original backup?

My goal is to get option 1.

Comment: So, what database is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally test it and yes, it works as expected. Once you stop the mirror and execute that instructionm, the mirror database becomes available with the last synchronized data.